# Encrypt Data in Kafka?

Tags: security, encryption, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

My team is using Kafka; we need to add encryption for security compliance reasons so that data is encrypted before it is published to Kafka and is decrypted when an authorized consumer consumes it from Kafka. I see Kafka offers TLS security options, but that doesn't seem to address our needs. TLS secures communication, but internally, data is still stored unencrypted. With some searching I see `KIP-317: End to end encryption` (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-317%3A+Add+end-to-end+data+encryption+functionality+to+Apache+Kafka
), which seems to address our use case, but that KIP seems like it stalled and never got finished.

One simple option is to add a simple custom encryption layer on top of the Kafka API. Programs publishing events to Kafka use an encryption library and encrypt the data before publishing events. Programs consuming events use an encryption library to decrypt messages consumed from Kafka. This would work and is simple.

Is there a better solution or a more standard solution?

Answer (score 3):

As you suggested  the easiest and most straight forward way to solve this is by encrypting the message before sending it and after you receive it at the application level and instead of sending an object you are sending a blob.

For a more elegant and optimized approach I would go with a custom serde though. One of the advantages of kafka is that the data is actually processed and manipulated in binary form so you are already using a serde to convert to and from binary.
Now by writing a [custom serde](https://www.ru-rocker.com/2020/06/01/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-kafka-message-using-custom-deserializers/) you should be able to get no overhead other than the obvious one required to encrypt/decrypt the bytes. Furthermore, going this way allows you to make the encryption completely transparent to the application. You could easily have an unencrypted dev environment while using the encrypted serde in production just by changing 2 lines in application.properties (or equivalent), no recompile required. Furthermore you can have a single person working on the serde while the rest of the team works on the software. When the serde is done, you just drop it in and you have encryption.

You could also try and check repositories like [this](https://github.com/salyh/kafka-end-2-end-encryption) and [this](https://github.com/QuickSign/kafka-encryption). You might be able to use them as they are, fork them or at least get some inspiration.

Disclaimer: Never tested any of the 3 links I referenced in this answer but the principle behind them is sound.